# How does the Pheromones status effect affect the Nemesis?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

The Scout's Pheromone Canister grenade as well as their crossbow weapon can apply the [Pheromones](https://deeprockgalactic.fandom.com/wiki/Status_Effects#Pheromones) status effect.

The Nemesis can grab the hologram from the Engineer's L.U.R.E grenade. The hologram is also attacked by other enemies. By default only the dwarves, Doretta and the hologram seem to be hostile from the point of view of the enemies, and they are the only things they attack (for example they never attack Bosco or the Engineer turrets).

However, the Pheromones status effect seems like it can turn enemies hostile from the point of view of enemies. If this also affects the Nemesis then it may make the crossbow a decent choice for Rival Presence missions.

When affected by Pheromones, does the Nemesis grab or at least *attempt* to grab other enemies, if the effect can be applied to it at all?

Comment: You said Doretta is viewed as both hostile and not hostile - which is it?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. I was thinking of an unstarted Doretta at the start of an escort mission but that was unclear and even with clarification it's confusing so I edited that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily today I managed to come across the Nemesis whilst having the crossbow with Pheremone bolts equipped.

After shooting the Nemesis with it, it seems the bugs did attack it, but it doesn't seem to be able to grab any of them, so it just kinda floats towards them and shoots it's little wall thingy, which does damage the bugs, so it is a nice way of clearing some bugs out, but doesn't direct grabbing towards the bugs (probably because bugs have no getting grabbed functionality)

I didn't dare checking if getting close while it is pheremoned would still make it grab you though, I have a feeling that might still be the case.